# In React Hook, how can I change specific value of useState array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
  let [_value, setValue] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]);
```

In this code, if I want to change the _value[3] how can I change value using setValue?

In my project, I have to change the _value[index] when the (rating) button is clicked.

So I have to dynamically change the _value[index].

If you know the answer, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There are generally a couple ways to update arrays in JavaScript. Importantly, whatever you do, you want to make sure you don't *mutate* the existing state.

One way is to make a shallow copy of the array, mutate the copy, and set the new state:

```js
function update(index, newValue) {
  // shallow copy
  const newArray = [..._value];
  // mutate copy
  newArray[index] = newValue;
  // set state
  setValue(newArray);
}
```

Another option is to `map` over the array, returning the new value when the index matches the desired index.

```js
function update(index, newValue) {
  const newArray = _value.map((v, i) => {
    if (i === index) return newValue;
    return v;
  });
  setValue(newArray);
}
```

Comment: While the `map` trick is neat, I'd recommend the first way of doing because it will allow you to add new entries to the array as well (e.g. add a 5th element to a 4 element array) whereas in the other it's silently ignored leading to future headaches.

Comment: @samthecodingman Using `.map` isn't really a trick, it's an established pattern for updating from *a* previous state to the next state. There is nothing inherently wrong with either of these methods other than they should probably use functional state updates to update from the previous state value versus whatever the value was when the callback was enqueued. Updating current state ***and*** adding new elements seems a bit like a broken abstraction (breaks Single Responsibility Principle) IMO, or at minimum is a very specific and limited  use-case.

Comment: While I'm aware of that map is an established pattern, the function's primary purpose is "change the value in the array at index `I` to `X`". Whether the index `I` is in the array's current bounds or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

In React you need to return a new state array reference. You can achieve this by mapping the previous state to the next state, using the index to match by, when the index matches return the new value, otherwise return the current value.

```
const updateByIndex = (newValue, index) => {
  setValue(values => values.map((value, i) => i === index ? newValue: value);
};
```